# How to use math.pow() to do calculations in Expression class?

Tags: java, math, infix-notation, postfix-mta

in my program I have written an evalPostfix() method that also uses my applyOperator() method.

However, one of the goals that I need to achieve is to perform exponentiation, using math.pow() to do the calculation. I also need to cast the end result back into an int.

I am unsure on how to get started, and how to implement Math.pow() into my evalPostfix() method in my Expression class.

Here is my code:

```
public class Expression {
   private static final String SPACE = " ";
   private static final String PLUS = "+";
   private static final String MINUS = "-";


   public static int rank(String operator) {
      switch (operator) {
         case "^":       //5
            return 3;
         case "*":
         case "/":
            return 2;
         case PLUS:
         case MINUS:     //2
            return 1;
         case "()":      //6
            return 0;
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static boolean isOperator(String token) {     //4
      if (rank(token) > 0){
         return true;
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static int applyOperator(String operator,int op1,int op2){     //7
      switch (operator) {
         case PLUS:
            return op1+op2;
         case MINUS:
            return op1-op2;
         case "*":
            return op1*op2;
         case "/":
            return op1/op2;
         default:
            return -1;
      }
   }

   public static String toPostfix(String infixExpr) {
      StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
      Stack<String> operators = new ArrayStack<>();        
      for (String token: infixExpr.split("\\s+")) {
         if (isOperator(token)) { // operator //4
            // pop equal or higher precedence
            while (!operators.isEmpty() &&
                  rank(operators.peek()) >= rank(token)) {
               output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
            }
            operators.push(token);
         } else {               // operand
            output.append(token + SPACE);
         }
      }
      while (!operators.isEmpty()) {
         output.append(operators.pop() + SPACE);
      }
      return output.toString();
   }

    public static int evalPostfix(String infixExpr) {     //8
      Stack <String> s = new ArrayStack<String>();
      String operand = null;
      for(int i = 0; i < infixExpr.length(); i++) {
         if (Character.isDigit(infixExpr.charAt(i)))
             s.push(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "");
         else {
             if (s.size() > 1) {
                int value1 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                int value2 = Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
                s.push(applyOperator(infixExpr.charAt(i) + "", value1, value2) + "");
             }
         }
      }
      return Integer.parseInt(s.pop());
      }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(rank("/"));
      String infix = ")a * b( * c + d ^ e / f";
      System.out.println(toPostfix(infix));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 7 * 3 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("*", 3, 7));
      System.out.print("Using applyOperator method, 50 + 12 = ");
      System.out.println(applyOperator("+", 50, 12));
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i correctly understood you, but if you're trying to calculate the result of a number to the power of some variable, why don't you use Math.pow(double a, double b) in java?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I am trying to calculate the result of a number to the power of 'n'. I was told to use Math.pow, but I am unsure how to set that up!

Comment: return (int) Math.pow( (double) op1, (double) op2);

Comment: Great! When I place that into my applyOperator method, it works! I just have to add case"^": before the return statement!

Comment: If you want to push it to your stack just use String.valueOf(Math.pow( (double) op1, (double) op2));